# Initializing object with asynchonous request

Tags: javascript

This is my object definition:

```
function DrilledLayer(sourceLayerName, sourceTableName, targetLayerName, targetFieldName, operators, baseLayer=false) {
        this.sourceLayerName = sourceLayerName;
        this.sourceTableName = sourceTableName;
        this.targetLayerName = targetLayerName;
        this.targetFieldName = targetFieldName;
        this.operators = operators;
        this.baseLayer = baseLayer;
        this.targetLayerId;
        this.drilledLayerId;
        this.selectedCode;
        this.redraw = false;

        this.getTargetLayerId(); //this function must initialize this.targetLayerId
}

DrilledLayer.prototype.getTargetLayerId = function(){
  $.soap({
    url: 'https://url/version_4.8/services/MapService',
    method: 'getLayersIdByName',
    appendMethodToURL: false,
    data : {
        mapInstanceKey: mapKey,
        layerName: this.targetLayerName,
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("error getLayersIdByName");
    },
    success: function(soapResponse){
        layerId = soapResponse.toJSON().Body.getLayersIdByNameResponse.getLayersIdByNameReturn.getLayersIdByNameReturn.text;
        this.targetLayerId = layerId;
    }
  });
}
```

This is how I create the object:

```
drillCs = new DrilledLayer("Drilled CS", "Cs_Franco_General.TAB", "RA_General", "Code_RA", "=")
```

If I look into drillCs object there is no targetLayerId property defined, but I know the soap request were made successfuly. Why?

Comment: `this` in your `success` function probably doesn't refer to your `DrilledLayer` object. You can assigned `this` to a local variable, and use that.

Comment: a) It's async and you're looking too early b) you did get [the `this` context of your callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) wrong

Comment: @Bergi: correct, a and b are the answers

Comment: @BelowtheRadar: For a) you might be interested in [this alternative pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24686979/1048572) for asynchronously initialisiing objects (instead of calling ajax from the constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in JavaScript is mostly set by how a function is called. `this` during the `success` callback won't be the same as `this` during your call to your `getTargetLayerId` function, you have to remember it.

In this case, the easiest way is probably with a variable:

```
DrilledLayer.prototype.getTargetLayerId = function(){
  var layer = this;                     // <=== Set it
  $.soap({
    url: 'https://url/version_4.8/services/MapService',
    method: 'getLayersIdByName',
    appendMethodToURL: false,
    data : {
        mapInstanceKey: mapKey,
        layerName: this.targetLayerName,
        },
    error: function(){
        alert("error getLayersIdByName");
     },
    success: function(soapResponse){
        layerId = soapResponse.toJSON().Body.getLayersIdByNameResponse.getLayersIdByNameReturn.getLayersIdByNameReturn.text;
        layer.targetLayerId = layerId; // <=== Use it
        }
    });
}
```

More *(on my blog)*:

- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Separately, of course, you won't see the properly until the async callback fires (which will be some time after the `new` call returns), but you seem to be comfortable with the async aspect of this.